# Why does $($) crash my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disclaimer: **Do not try this at home**

---

Why, if I am using jQuery, does `$($)` freeze the page?

Comment: The dollar is a function. It runs into endless recursion if you call it with itself.

Comment: Why does this question need protection?

Comment: I should call it, "jQueryCursion", or "jQueRecursive" !

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`$($)` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready($)`. So, it will run the function (when the DOM is ready or directly when this is already the case).

The function passed to `.ready` is passed the jQuery function for convenience (especially useful when you're in `noConflict` mode). So, `$($)` will call `$` with `$` as argument - and everything will happen again, which is endless recursion.

---

Another explanation:

1. You call `$($)`.
2. jQuery adds the function argument (`$`) to an internal `ready` list.
3. Some time later, jQuery sees that the DOM is ready and thinks: "Let's call all functions in the `ready` list".
4. The only function in the `ready` list is `$`, so it calls `$`.
5. jQuery [sees](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L389) it should pass the `$` function as the argument to those functions.
6. It calls `$` with `$` as argument.
7. The `$` function sees a function as its argument, but because the DOM is ready, it calls the function directly (there is nothing to wait for).
8. The `$` function is called with `$` as the argument.
9. Everything happens again since step 7 applies.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yes - `$(func)` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(func)`.

Comment: You'd think with all the safety checks it's doing, this would we trivial to add...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - `$()` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Your comment is slightly different than your original answer :P

Comment: @pimvdb: You didn't have `($)` before ;)

Comment: @JAAulde: No, only when `$` takes a function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - now you're just being obtuse.

Comment: @JAAulde: Not particularly; you're just being unnecessarily imprecise. The distinction is highly pertinent to this question, since we're analysing what a call to `$` does with a specific argument. Of course in this case it _is_ a shortcut for `$(document).ready()` because `$` _is_ a function

Comment: It may be interesting to note that this also works from the console, well after the document has loaded

Comment: But how does the internal `$` get called? `$(function $(){console.log(1)})` doesn't simulate this behavior.

Comment: @Incognito it gets called because it gets set as the onload event handler. I assume calling it with no arguments also acts as an onload handler, or I don't see how this would work

Comment: @GGG Don't make an ass out of you and umptions. ;).

Comment: @Incognito: That's because you don't use the argument. Try `$(function f($_again) { $_again(f); })`.

Answer (score 23):

Now this is what I call "jQueryception."

You're calling whole jQuery library within jQuery.

**More information;**

When you call "$" (defined as jQuery core function by jQuery library) it initializes the jQuery and tries to call the defined function if it has one. When you actually call "$($);" you'll be calling jQuery inside jQuery and it'll be calling jQuery again and again.

**From jQuery 1.7.1 source code;**

```
    // HANDLE: $(function)
    // Shortcut for document ready
    } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
        return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
    }
```

And

```
rootjQuery = jQuery(document);
```

As you can see, when you call $($); it tries to call jQuery with the name of your function and if you call it with jQuery again same thing will happen endlessly as I've explained before.

Comment: @Diabolic - Can you explain a little bit more so this answer does not get deleted?

Comment: I would be worth expanding this answer just a teeny bit.

Comment: Is there a plugin to stop this?

Answer (score 3):

`$` is an alias to the `jQuery` factory function.

The `jQuery` factory function, when passed a function as first param, runs that function at `document.ready` and passes `jQuery` as the first parameter to it.

Thus you end up with a infinite recursion starting when `document.ready` is reached.

Comment: How does this work when you run it from the console after the document has loaded (with the same result)?

Comment: @GGG If `document.ready` has already been reached, `jQuery` goes ahead and runs the function given to it upon invocation.

Comment: I was able to crash my browser (at least hang a while) by calling $($); from Firebug console.